# Can't access item in ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight

I define my `ItemsControl` that contain `RadioButton`s.

I want to access the `Items` contained in `ItemsControl` that are attached as binding child - and when I try to access the `ItemsControl.Items` I can't see the `RadioButtons`.

The code:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Key}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are setting the ItemTemplate of the control, ant not its items. To add items do it like this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl" >
    <ItemsControl.Items>
            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Key}" />
    </ItemsControl.Items> 
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: But in this case - how can i do the Binding ? I can't use the itemsControl.ItemsSource and tying to do itemsControl.DataContext is fail.